# For a matrix A, how to prove $\min \|A\|_1$ is equal to $\min \sum_i\sum_j |a_{ij}|$ where $a_{ij}$ is the element of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, normed-spaces, machine-learning

The primary optimziation problem is shown as
$$\min_A \|X-DA\|^2_F+\beta\|A\|_1,$$
where $X\in\Bbb{R}^{m\times p}$,$D\in\Bbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $A\in\Bbb{R}^{n\times p}$ are three matrices. Let $A=A^1-A^2$, $A^1\in\Bbb{R}^{n\times p}$ and $A^2\in\Bbb{R}^{n\times p}$ are defined as
$$
  A^1_{ij} =
\begin{cases}
a_{ij},  & \text{if $a_{ij}>0$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
  A^2_{ij} =
\begin{cases}
|a_{ij}|,  & \text{if $a_{ij}<0$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $a_{ij}$ is the $i$th row and $j$th column of $A$.

A paper said that this problem can be transformed as
$$\min_{A^1,A^2} \|X-D(A^1-A^2)\|^2_F+\beta e_n^T(A^1+A^2)e_p$$
$$s.t. A^1\geq 0, A^2\geq 0.$$
where $e_n\in\Bbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ and $e_p\in\Bbb{R}^{p \times 1}$ are two all-one vectors. $A^1\geq 0$ and $A^2\geq 0$ denote that all elements in $A^1$ and $A^2$ are nonnegative.

My question is how to prove the primary problem and the transformed problem are equivalent?

Comment: You have that $A = A^1-A^2$ and isn't $||A||_1=\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$ by definition?

Comment: @LeonSot It depends. Another possibility for $\|A\|_1$ is to denote the operator norm induced by $\mathbf R^n$'s $\|\cdot\|_1$. But I guess, you are right here.

Comment: @LeonSot should't $\|A\|_1=\max_j \sum_i |a_{ij}|$ ?